# Set JFrame size after JTable size

Tags: java, user-interface, resize, jtable, jframe

I want the size of the frame to adjust to the number of cells in the table. Just setting the size with integers isn't flexible enough, since I can't see all the cells if the table's size exceeds the frame's size.

I've tried this:

```
table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(table.WIDTH, table.HEIGHT));
```

It doesn't work as desired, since I have to manually resize the frame with the mouse to see all the cells. Is there a method for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change the size of the `JTable` using `setPreferredSize`, this will prevent the table from been able to show rows or columns that extend beyond the range of the size you set.

`JTable` should be embedded within a `JScrollPane` and the `JScrollPane` added to the frame...

[image: Table in scroll pane]

```
add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

This will allow the table to exceed the frames viewable bounds, but allow you to scroll and see them

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details